# Symfony upload file in MySQL blob

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to save a `PDF` file in `MySQL` but It doesn't work. It seems `Symfony` and `Doctrine` are not able to save a file in blob row...

When I submit my form with the file, everything seems ok. But when I download the file from my database I have this:

> /tmp/phpssT5KJ

It's like the blob row was the path of my file?

All my google research provide a way for moving a file but I don't want to move my file to `/web/{something}`...

Is it possible? Why my row contains the path instead of the file?

Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

So I found how to fix it:

Like the usual method when you save only the path you add a variable $file and the method upload. (On your form you use $file and not your field)

Upload needs this code:

```
public function upload(){  
    $pdfFile = $this->file;   
    $this->setPdf(file_get_contents($pdfFile));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That path is path to your TMP location of the file. You need to put that files content in your DB.

Comment: I know that path is the TMP location of the file... But why Symfony/Doctrine puts the path instead of the file in my DB? How can I put the file if Symfony/Doctrine don't?